# Make two Frames occupy 50% of the available width each?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

How can I make two `Frame`s occupy 50% each of the available width of the window?

Right now I'm just letting the contents dictate the widths and using `pack(side=Tkinter.LEFT)`, and obviously that doesn't make them both equal width.

I tried using `grid()` instead, but then I couldn't get them to resize when I resize the window.

**EDIT**

Note that I want to be able to resize the window and the frames should resize with it to always be 50% of the width.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use grid, using the `uniform` option. Put both halves in a "uniform group" by setting the `uniform` option to the same value for both, and they will be the same size. To get the columns to grow/shrink with the window, give them equal weight.

Example:

```
frame1 = tk.Frame(parent, ...)
frame2 = tk.Frame(parent, ...)

frame1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
frame2.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew")

parent.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1, uniform="group1")
parent.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1, uniform="group1")
parent.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I edited the answer according to the comment above by @BillalBEGUERADJ, works great now.

Answer (score 0):

You should use expand and fill if using the pack method

Example

```
import Tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

left_frame = tk.Frame(root, bg = 'yellow')
left_frame.pack(side = tk.LEFT, expand = True, fill = tk.BOTH)

right_frame = tk.Frame(root, bg = 'lime')
right_frame.pack(side = tk.LEFT, expand = True, fill = tk.BOTH)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This won't make the frames equal width, will it? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes. The problem is that as soon as I add any contents to the frames, they adjust their width (if the content isn't exactly equal width in both frames).

Comment: Hmm, been going at fixing that and I can't seem to find a reliable non-hacky way of doing it using pack method.

Answer (score -1):

I finally came up with a hack that works correctly.

In the start, I create 2 frames, one of them has a label with (intentionally) a long text, and the other one a simple button. You can add as many widgets to both frames as you want.

The idea is to bind a callback method which takes in consideration the new dimensions of the main window (in case the user stretches or moves the window with the mouse) and resize the 2 frames consequently.

This is achieved using [`<Configure>`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm) event which provides the new dimensions to set to our 3 main widgets (the main window and the 2 frames).

The next step is to fix the problem you mentioned below ***@StevenSummers*** ' answer. To do that, we can rely on [`grid_propagate()`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm#Tkinter.Grid.grid_propagate-method) which enables or disables the geometry propagation.

**Program:**

Let us put these ideas into action (a quick dirty example to implement the ideas; I did the same for the height, but you can ignore it if you do not need it):

```
import Tkinter as Tk

# Main window
master = Tk.Tk()

# Callback event that resizes the main components
def resize_it(event):
    global master # Main Window
    global a # Red Frame
    global b # Blue Frame
    #Reconfigure the main window's and frames' dimensions      
    a.configure(width=event.width/2, height=event.height/2)
    b.configure(width=event.width/2, height=event.height/2)
    master.configure(width=event.width, height=event.height)

#Create a red (first) Frame
a = Tk.Frame(master, bg='red')
a.pack(side='left', expand=True, fill=Tk.BOTH)

# Draw a button on frame a
a1 = Tk.Button(a, text='Button 1')
a1.grid(row=0, column=0)
# Disable geometry propagation
a.grid_propagate(0)   

#Create a blue (second) Frame
b = Tk.Frame(master,  bg='blue')
b.pack(side='left', expand=True, fill=Tk.BOTH)
# Draw a label on frame b
l1 = Tk.Label(b, text='Label 1Label 1Label 1Label 1Label 1Label 1Label 1Label 1Label 1Label 1Label 1Label 1Label 1Label 1Label 1Label 1')
l1.grid(row=0, column=0)
# Disable geometry propagation on frame b
# Note: always after adding ALL the desired widgets to b. Same note for frame b
b.grid_propagate(0)    

master.bind('<Configure>', resize_it)
#Start program
master.mainloop()
```

**Demo:**

The output of the above program is always the same result you expect whenever you resize the main window using the mouse and whatever number of widgets you add to the 2 frames:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I want to be able to resize the window, this solution doesn't seem to allow that?

Comment: @BadCash I did a hack to resolve your problem. Check my edit.